# How to get unicode from emoji in Android?

Tags: android

How can I get unicode from emoji in android? for example I have a text "hi (smiling face with open mouth)" I want the string as "hi \ud83d". I have tried to convert it into bytes and then convert to string. But no hope.

Comment: Well, *some* hope if you show us what you tried. Then we can help.

Comment: `editText1.getText().toString().getBytes("UTF-8").toString()` and `Base64.encodeToString(editText1.getText().toString(), 0)`. I just google it. But I got the encoding of emoji in iOS but not in Android

Answer (score 5):

you can get the unicode of the emoticon as

StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava();

and decode it back to emoticon u can use

StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava();

Comment: In my case escapeJava() not works with & and + symbols.

Answer (score 2):

In my case all message disappears after symbols & and + when I use StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava() method. So, this code works well for me:

```
private String encodeMessage(String message) {
    message = message.replaceAll("&", ":and:");
    message = message.replaceAll("\\+", ":plus:");
    return StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(message);
}

private String decodeMessage(String message) {
    message = message.replaceAll(":and:", "&");
    message = message.replaceAll(":plus:", "+");
    return StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(message);
}
```

Comment: for StringEscapeUtils use this gradle "implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-text:1.6'" old one deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

At last I got the answer

I don't know I am on the right Way. Anybody who knows better answer will be appretiated

```
public static String escapeJavaString(String st){
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < st.length(); i++) {
                 char c = st.charAt(i);
                 if(!Character.isLetterOrDigit(c) && !Character.isSpaceChar(c)&& !Character.isWhitespace(c) ){
                     String unicode = String.valueOf(c);
                     int code = (int)c;
                     if(!(code >= 0 && code <= 255)){
                         unicode = "\\\\u"+Integer.toHexString(c);
                     }
                     builder.append(unicode);
                 }
                 else{
                     builder.append(c);
                 }
            }
            Log.i("Unicode Block", builder.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }
```